# How to solve DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502

Tags: java, database

```
2015-08-28 18:12:19.047-Fri Aug 28 18:12:19 IST 2015DB2 Connection established -->com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b@c26e4a
2015-08-28 18:12:20.030-Execution failed ======> alter table BLP.COUNTER_EXTRACTION_REQUEST alter column SCHEME_ID set not null
2015-08-28 18:12:20.032-Error code for failure ======> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=SCHEME_ID, DRIVER=3.63.123
2015-08-28 18:12:20.044-Execution failed ======> alter table BLP.COUNTER_EXTRACTION_REQUEST alter column SCHEME_TYPE set not null
2015-08-28 18:12:20.044-Error code for failure ======> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=SCHEME_TYPE, DRIVER=3.63.123
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Jayaprakash. Some points to help us help you:
1) Please frame your question properly, along with correct formatting, code in this case.
2) Do let us know what you've already tried. This helps us not shoot in the dark.

Answer (score 10):

According to [this page](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.codes/src/tpc/db2z_n.dita), DB2 SQL error code `-407` means:

> -407 - AN UPDATE, INSERT, OR SET VALUE IS NULL, BUT THE OBJECT COLUMN column-name CANNOT CONTAIN NULL VALUES

The State Code is saying the same thing:

> 23502 - An insert or update value is null, but the column cannot contain null values.

But you are apparently getting this error for this ALTER statement:

```
alter table BLP.COUNTER_EXTRACTION_REQUEST alter column SCHEME_ID set not null
```

So I suspect that in this context the error code means that the column currently contains null values, and you can't add a "not null" constraint to the column until you have eliminated them.

Answer (score 0):

two ways:

First one: Drop the column from the table. Re-create with not null.

second one: update the column=' default value' where column date = null and change to null.